# Gulp 4 - watch not watching changes

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

Today I migrated to *Gulp 4*, but I'm not able to get my *watch* function to work.

```
// Watch
gulp.task('watch', gulp.series('typescript', 'sass', 'browserSync', function(){
  gulp.watch('./app/styles/**/*.scss', gulp.series('sass'));
  gulp.watch('app/scripts/**/*.ts', gulp.series('typescript'));
  gulp.watch('./app/*.html', browserSync.reload);
}));
```

`typescript`, `sass`, `browserSync` will run but *watch* does not react to file changes.

Comment: Helped me: [API - Watching Files](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/watching-files)

Comment: @vsync That seems to be the key to my issue right now, but how do I implement it? What is the `cb` in the API example `function css(cb) {
  // body omitted
  cb();`?
}

Comment: [This article](https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-wordpress-initial-setup/) explains `cb` and other related issues.

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same problem. You don't actually have a reference to the initialized `browserSync` inside your `watch` gulp task. Instead of having your `browserSync.init` function in a separate `browserSync` gulp task, move it to inside your `watch` task, and it should work. Hope this helps!

**Example:**

```
gulp.task('watch', gulp.series(function (){
  browserSync.init({
    proxy:"http://localhost:8888",
    injectChanges: true,
    plugins: ["bs-html-injector?files[]=*.html"]
  });
  var html = gulp.watch('development/index.html');
  html.on('change', function(path, stats) {
    console.log('you changed the html');
    browserSync.notify("Compiling, please wait!");
    browserSync.reload("index.html");
  })
  var js = gulp.watch('development/**/*.js');
  js.on('change', function(path, stats) {
    console.log('you changed the js');
    browserSync.notify("Compiling, please wait!");
    browserSync.reload();
  })
  var css = gulp.watch('development/**/*.css');
  css.on('change', function(path, stats) {
    console.log('you changed the css');
    browserSync.notify("Injecting CSS!");
    browserSync.reload("*.css");
  })
}));
```

Comment: This could benefit from putting the actual compiling task calls in here for clarity/completion, in other words your example watches but does nothing :)

Comment: @neilVanLandigham your answer save my day.but I have update it for gulp-sass

Answer (score 1):

Change `gulp.watch('app/scripts/**/*.ts', gulp.series('typescript'));` to a absolute `gulp.watch('./app/scripts/**/*.ts', gulp.series('typescript'));`

Also i normally stick this syntax, per task.

```
var watcher = gulp.watch('js/**/*.js', gulp.parallel('concat', 'uglify'));
watcher.on('change', function(path, stats) {
  console.log('File ' + path + ' was changed');
});
```

Comment: That one is missing because I was looking for problem in paths. Does not help.

Comment: Its more explicit always work for me, the parallel is not neccessary change to series in your case

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues too, and i found this  [tutorial of gulp 4](https://hackersandslackers.com/upgrading-to-gulp-4/), this is my gulpfile to compile scss and watch the Scss files, concat and compile to a main.min.css with autoprefix.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    concat  = require('gulp-concat'),
    autoprefixer    = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass');

//task para o sass

var paths = {
  styles: {
    src: 'scss/**/*.scss',
    dest: 'css'
  }
};

function styles() {
  return gulp
    .src(paths.styles.src, {
      sourcemaps: true
    })
  .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
  .pipe(concat('main.min.css'))
  .pipe(autoprefixer({
    browser: ['last 2 version', '> 5%'],
    cascade: false
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.dest));
}

function watch() {
  gulp.watch(paths.styles.src, styles);
}

var build = gulp.parallel(styles, watch);
gulp.task(build);
gulp.task('default', build);
```

I think that on the gulp v4 you need to use the **gulp.parallel**. I'm digging to learn more about the new version.